# Elegantly handle different parameter types

Tags: python

I have a function that, in the simplest of cases, operates on an iterable of items.

```
def foo(items):
    for item in items:
        # do stuff
```

Sometimes, I do not want to pass it an iterable of items directly, but rather an object that provides a method to get the iterable:

```
def foo(obj):
    for item in obj.iteritems():
        # do same stuff as above
```

I can merge these two cases like this:

```
def foo(obj):
    try:
        items = obj.iteritems()
    except ValueError:
        items = obj
    for item in items:
        # do stuff
```

This works just fine. Now I get a third use case that looks like this:

```
def foo(objs):
    for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(obj.iteritems() for obj in objs):
        # do same stuff again
```

I can still use the `try-except` approach, since the interfaces are incompatible. However, the nested try catch would start to become very ugly. More so when I want to add a fourth use-case. Is there any way to solve this without nesting the `try`-blocks?

Comment: Ah, I *so* wish there were proper function overloads in Python!

Comment: @André: almost always in Python, if you want that sort of function/method overloads, you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: But what's the problem with sending explicitly the iterable? too verbose?

Comment: Yes. All the use-cases are equally frequent, and some of them are just to verbose.

Comment: @Chris: yeah, *almost*. And I *almost* always find a better alternative ;-) I've seen far too much Python classes with `addfoo()`, `addbar()` and `addmeh()` methods to avoid run-time type checking in single `add()` method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, you should probably use at least two methods here,the third just calling the first with the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` result. You could also potentially have a use for *args; it depends on your precise case (providing a real example is helpful). You can also use a simple helper function to return the right type of iterator.

Perhaps this might work out:

```
def _foo_iter(obj):
    try:
        return obj.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:
        return obj

def foo(*objs):
    for obj in objs:
        for item in _foo_iter(obj):
```

Comment: The code I have provided is pretty close to the real thing, only the names are changed.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: but you haven't explained how precisely you're using it and what for.  For some things there might be a better way which hasn't occurred to you (that often happens, e.g. in one question I was using a custom function when `x in y` would have done just as well but for some reason it hadn't occurred to me)

Comment: The function is a generator the calculates a certain property for each of the items.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: thinking over it more, I think this is actually precisely what you need, unless you *really* want `foo([a, b, c])` rather than `foo(a, b, c)` for your chain case.  By using *args, it's put in a list and so you can just use `for obj in objs`. And whether it is or isn't precisely what you want - the `_foo_iter` helper function should be what you need to make the code less messy.

Comment: @Chris: I think so too. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: It would be nice if down-voters explained why they downvoted things that weren't obviously wrong/not what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Must agree with Chris: the magic understand-everything input is going to turn around and bite you. If you pass it an iterable of objects-with-iterables of iterables, how do you specify at what level to actually start processing data?

Far better to stick with "either a list or a generator" as input, then pre-process your calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an object is iterable:

```
import collections
isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable)
```

This should get you rid of some problems.

Also, a way to handle such problems is by using recursivity (don't know if it's applicable though):

```
def foo(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
        for el in obj:
            foo(el)
    # now do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

`hasattr(object, name)`

```
    if hasattr(obj, '__iter__'):
        return [o for o in obj]
    elif hasattr(obj, 'iteritems'):
        return [o for o in obj.iteritems()]
    elif isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return [o.iteritems() for o in [o for o in obj]]
    else:
        raise TypeError

class Bar(list):
    def iteritems(self):
        return self.__iter__()

print foo([1,2,3])
print foo(Bar([1,2,3]))
print foo([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
print foo(1)

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print foo(1)
  File "test.py", line 11, in foo
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

Comment: `hasattr` is essentially just a `try` around `getattr`.

Comment: @chris No, It does not force to nest exceptions e.g its its more readable. Which is what the question is asking.